# How to get field's tag without using the field name as string?

Tags: go, reflection

Is it possible to fetch a field tag using a function that receives only the struct and the field itself ?

I know that I can do a thing like this:

```golang
reflect.TypeOf(x).FieldByName("FieldNameAsString").Tag
```

But I don't want to use the field's name as string in this case because it could be renamed in the future, so it is better to use the field itself instead.

```golang
type MyStruct struct {
    MyField string `thetag:"hello"`
}

func main() {
    x := MyStruct{}
    getTag(x, x.MyField)
}
```

Comment: How could `x.MyField` tell you which field? If there's only one `string` field then you can infer it, but once you have multiple fields of the same type there's no information to identify it.

Comment: That's not how reflection works. Besides, if the field name changes, you'd still have to update the code, so what difference would it make?

Comment: Are you trying to find the tagged field (i.e. the one tagged `hello`) - regardless of its name (`MyField`)? If so, then yes this is possible. But please clarify your question first.

Comment: @Adrian You're right, if the field name changes I still have to update the code but I can rely on tools that can do this to me. I can refactor/rename the field using these tools but if I "harcoded" the field name as string it will require much more effort to look at the entire codebase searching for this terms.

Comment: @colminator no, what I want is to get the field tag, on my example "hello"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use offsets to find the field:

```
// getTag returns the tag for a field given a pointer to
// a struct and a pointer to the field in that struct.
func getTag(pv interface{}, pf interface{}) reflect.StructTag {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(pv)
    offset := reflect.ValueOf(pf).Pointer() - v.Pointer()

    t := v.Type().Elem()
    for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
        f := t.Field(i)
        if f.Offset == offset {
            return f.Tag
        }
    }
    return ""
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/npXraSQ5U8m).

The code above assumes that the garbage collector does not move the struct between the to calls to [Pointer](https://godoc.org/reflect#Value.Pointer). This assumption is true today, but may not true in the future.  Use the [unsafe](https://godoc.org/unsafe#Offsetof) package to make the code safe against future changes to the garbage collector:

```
// getTag returns the tag for a field with the given offset
// in the struct pointed to by pv.
func getTag(pv interface{}, offset uintptr) reflect.StructTag {
    t := reflect.TypeOf(pv).Elem()
    for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
        f := t.Field(i)
        if f.Offset == offset {
            return f.Tag
        }
    }
    return ""
}
```

Call it like this:

```
x := MyStruct{}
fmt.Println(getTag(&x, unsafe.Offsetof(x.MyField)))
```

[Run it on the Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/x2MmJyBOsAZ).

Comment: Nice one. But is it safe ? I mean, can this offset change after a garbage collection?

Comment: @invalid_address See updated answer on how to use the unsafe package to make the code safe against changes to the garbage collector.